# The type int is not compatible with type seq<'a>

Tags: f#

consider i have the following code,

```
let sqx= seq [1; 2; 3; 4;]
let sqy= seq [1; 2; 3; 4;]

let func sqx sqy = seq{ 
         for x in sqx do
            for y in sqy do yield x,y    } 

let cartesian sqx sqy= Seq.map (func sqx) sqy 

cartesian sqx sqy
```

at the last line i am facing with the erorr:

```
The type int is not compatible with type seq<'a>
```

I have also tried to work with `Seq.map2`, but still the same problem.

Comment: `Seq.map` is passing `func` the _elements_ of `sqy`, but `func` wants `sqy` itself.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the types involved, it may help you understand why the compiler complains.

The type of `func` is `seq<'a> -> seq<'b> -> seq<'a * 'b>`. That is, incidentally, also the type of `Seq.zip`; consider replacing `func` with `Seq.zip`.

The type of `Seq.map` is `('a -> 'b) -> seq<'a> -> seq<'b>`.

If you look at `cartesian`, it simply it calls `Seq.map` with two arguments. The second argument is easiest to think about. From the type of `Seq.map`, we know that it must be `seq<'something>`.

That also means that `func sqx` *must* fit into the type `'a -> 'b`, or, more specifically `'something -> 'b`.

The type of `func sqx`, on the other hand, is `seq<'b> -> seq<'a * 'b>`, because it's partially applied. In other words, the input is `seq<'b>`.

This *must* fit into the `'something -> 'b` argument passed to `Seq.map`, so `'something` must be `seq<'b>`, and the return type is inferred to be `seq<'a * 'b>`. Thus, the overall type of `cartesian` is `seq<'a> -> seq<#seq<'c>> -> seq<seq<'a * 'c>>`.

The first argument to `cartesian` must be `seq<'a>`. That's OK, because `sqx` has the type `seq<int>`.

The next argument to `cartesian` must be `seq<#seq<'c>>`, but `sqy` has the type `seq<int>`. That's not the same type, and that's the reason `cartesian sqx sqy` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you want something like `seq [(1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); ...]` (which would be the cartesian product of your `sqx` and `sqy`) and indeed you have this already implemented:

```
> func sqx sqy;;
val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); ...]
```

but maybe you want to apply some function to all combinations of `x in sqx` and `y in sqy`? Then can modify your code a bit:

```
let allWith f sqx sqy = 
    seq{ for x in sqx do
         for y in sqy do 
         yield f x y }
```

and have some fun:

```
> allWith (fun x y -> (x,y)) sqx sqy;;
val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3); (1, 4); ...]
> allWith (+) sqx sqy;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [2; 3; 4; 5; ...]
```

---

or maybe you want to write a function that takes the cartesian product of a sequence of sequences? This is more fun:

```
let rec cartesian (xss : 'a seq seq) =
    if Seq.isEmpty xss then Seq.singleton Seq.empty else
    let first = Seq.head xss
    let rests = cartesian (Seq.tail xss)
    seq { for x in first do
          for xs in rests do
          yield seq { yield x; yield! xs }
    }
```

here is a simple example:

```
> cartesian [[1;2;3];[4];[5;6]] |> Seq.toArray;;
val it : seq<int> [] =
  [|seq [1; 4; 5]; seq [1; 4; 6]; seq [2; 4; 5]; seq [2; 4; 6]; seq [3; 4; 5];
    seq [3; 4; 6]|]
```